# SELECT multiple WHERE in same column

Tags: php, mysql

I want choose month and year from the same column. How can I separate month and year from the column?

```
<label>Bulan :</label>
<select name="month">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Januari</option>
    <option value="2">Februari</option>
    <option value="3">Mac</option>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>

<label>Tahun :</label>
<select name="year">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Hantar" >

<?php
if(isset($_POST['year']) && ($_POST['month']))
{
    $tarikh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
    $tarikh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
```

I am running this query

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM pelanggan 
          WHERE (MONTH(tarikh) = '$tarikh') 
          and (YEAR(tarikh) = '$tarikh')";
```

Why doesn't the output display? What is wrong with the above query?

Comment: Because you're overwriting the variable values and I'm sure you don't have dates with month 2017 in your database. Also learn to use parameters immediately rather than escaping strings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

in query string you use same variable for month and year

add different variable names in

```
$tarikhMonth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
$tarikhYear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
```

and

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM pelanggan 
         WHERE (MONTH(tarikh) = '$tarikhMonth') 
         and (YEAR(tarikh) = '$tarikhYear')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your $tarikh variable.  Naming them $month and $year should work.

I would use PDO instead of trying to escape strings manually as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different variable names for the month and year. Try this

```
<label>Bulan :</label>&nbsp;<select name="month">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Januari</option>
          <option value="2">Februari</option>
          <option value="3">Mac</option>...

        </select><label>Tahun :</label>&nbsp;<select name="year">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
        </select><input type="submit" value="Hantar" ></td>


        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['year']) && ($_POST['month']))
        {
        $tarikh_month = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
        $tarikh_year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);


$query ="SELECT * FROM pelanggan 
          WHERE (MONTH(tarikh) = '$tarikh_month') 
          and (YEAR(tarikh) = '$tarikh_year')";
```